# Callbacks for arguments in Scilab

Tags: user-interface, callback, scope, scilab

I'm writing a GUI in Scilab and assigning callbacks to `pushbutton` controls. When a button is pressed, another control is affected, e.g. text inside a textbox changes. This whole routine itself (creation and initialization of the GUI) lives inside a function, that is I have to call my `create_my_gui()` to run it.

My problem lies in variable scope and callback usage. Several of my buttons affect several other controls in exactly the same way, so I would like to use the same callback function and pass a handle to the control I'm trying to affect into the callback.

For example when I press the *N*-th button, I'd like to pass the handle *N*-th control into the callback:

```
function buttonPressCallback  ( controlHandle )
    controlHandle.string = 'Button pressed!';
endfunction
```

The problem is that callbacks are defined as strings:

```
myButton3.callback = 'buttonPressCallback ( myTextBox3 )'
```

And after I've run my `create_my_gui()` function, all variables go out of scope and are destroyed, *including* handles to all controls. When I press the button, Scilab tries to run whatever string was specified as the callback and complains about the variable, `myTextBox3` for example, not existing.

Is there a way I can refer to uicontrols in Scilab after the function that created them exited? I understand that Scilab has very peculiar ways of addressing things and perhaps I'm just not thinking in correct Scilab programming patters just yet. Is there the "right way" of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a decent solution. Each `uicontrol` can be *tagged* by setting `myUicontrol.tag = 'my_tag';`. This `uicontrol` can then be found globally using `my_handle = findobj('tag','my_tag');`.

Answer (score 0):

You can acccess the calling uicontrol object via gcbo, like:

```
get(gcbo,"value");
```